# How to create binary matrix given indices in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Suppose I have a tf tensor with indices for two samples:

```
x = [[2,3,5], [5,7,5]]
```

I would like to create a tensor with a certain shape `(samples, 10)`, where the indices of each sample in `x` are set to 1 and the rest to 0 like this:

```
output = [[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

What is the best way to do this, without creating a lot of intermediary matrices?

The closest I got was using `tf.scatter_nd`, but I couldn't figure out how to transform `x` and the `updates` correctly, except manually adding additional information like this:

```
>>> tf.cast(tf.scatter_nd([[0,2], [0,3], [0,5], [1,5], [1,7], [1,5]], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] , 
[2, 10]) > 0, dtype="int64")
<tf.Tensor: id=1191, shape=(2, 10), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]])>
```

Also, this approach will aggregate duplicate indices at first, which makes an intermediary boolean matrix necessary. (This I could live with though, the main problem is getting from `x` to a matrix with shape `(samples, 10)` where non-existent indices are 0 for each sample.)

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: [tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer#sequences_to_matrix) has this functionality, but I'd like to use this in a custom keras layer, so I'm looking for a solution that uses tensorflow ops only.

Comment: keras embedding layer supports this kind of input, can be used to subclass or as an example

Comment: I think you are right that this could be implemented using an embedding layer initialized with an identity matrix, followed by a max or sum operation. But as the vocabulary size (10 in the example above) can get pretty big, I'd like to avoid creating this huge identity matrix, and the intermediary output of the embedding layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution (tensorflow 2.2.0):

```
class BinarizeSequence(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    """
    Transforms an integer sequence into a binary representation
    with shape (samples, vocab_size).

    Example:
    In: [[2,3,5], [5,7,5]]
    Out: [[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]]

    By default the output is returned as SparseTensor.
    Use dense_output=True if you need a dense representation.
    """

    def __init__(self, vocab_size, dense_output=False, **kwargs):
        super(BinarizeSequence, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.vocab_size = vocab_size
        self.dense_output = dense_output

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config().copy()
        config.update(
            {"vocab_size": self.vocab_size, "dense_output": self.dense_output}
        )
        return config

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        # create indices for binarized representation
        x = tf.cast(x, dtype=tf.int32)
        x_1d = tf.reshape(x, [-1])
        sample_dim = tf.repeat(
            tf.range(tf.shape(x)[0], dtype=tf.int32), tf.shape(x)[1]
        )
        indices = tf.transpose(tf.stack([sample_dim, x_1d]))

        # only keep unique indices
        # (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42245425/979377)
        indices64 = tf.bitcast(indices, type=tf.int64)
        unique64, idx = tf.unique(indices64)
        unique_indices = tf.bitcast(unique64, type=tf.int32)

        # build binarized representation
        updates = tf.ones(tf.shape(unique_indices)[0])
        output_shape = [tf.shape(x)[0], self.vocab_size]
        if self.dense_output:
            output = tf.scatter_nd(unique_indices, updates, output_shape)
        else:
            output = tf.sparse.SparseTensor(
                tf.cast(unique_indices, tf.int64), updates, output_shape
            )
        return output
```

Comment: Note to future readers: Also check out the `tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.TextVectorization` layer.